# Google Maps API Key wont authenticate correctly

Tags: php, google-maps, keycode

I am attempting to integrate a Google map into my website, which will use a postcode to Lat/lng location system to plot points. But for some reason Google keeps disabling my map 2-3 seconds after it appears. The keycode is brand new and Ive checked and copied it several times to be sure. The tutorial on it says to create a browser key which I have done, I enter it in the line :

```
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAlvGtJcsp_qZy_U1deMqG8saGDQb4QU88&sensor=false">
```

The rest of the code is a direct lift from the tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#HelloWorld as I am still trying to just get the map showing online.

Ive read dozens of pages on this and none can explain why its invalid, I even tried creating a server key using the IP address but that was bounced too. I would have contacted Google Support directly but they require an upgraded plan for that apparently.

Anyone have any idea whats going on? For reference, the complete script is shown below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm not after a quick fix as I need to understand what's wrong, but I cant work out where to look as Ive followed to tutorial exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually without the API key, you should see the Map also! Here there is a [live version](http://jsfiddle.net/pnvt19jj/) 
BTW: probably you wrote a bad domain address for the browser key, try not to write any domain address.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Comment: I checked the domain name again and it is exaxtly as it says it should be typed, */<website name after the www.>/* As for removing the key, your right, it works. But surely the key must play some part in operations on a larger scale otherwise why use one at all! Do you have an example of a domain that is registered for google maps so I can compare syntax? Thanks!

Comment: The key is only to track how many queries that your website is using. If you only show some points on the map, you do not need the key. BTW: i am not so sure that i can post a key on stackoverflow

You need to check if you completely sure about your domain name with the key!

Comment: I went back to the domain name, ignored the example and just wrote the https address and it worked! it was their example format that was invalidating it! thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, you can use Https Protocol also in the domain